# Display Relating Entry based on Page Routing

Tags: templating, routes

I'm trying to create a submission page at the following URL structure

```
/campaigns/this-is-a-test-creation/submissions
```

As you can see `/campaigns/` is the Channel and the `/this-is-a-test-creation/` is the entry slug. I'm trying to currently set up my page using routing and fetch the related entry, but I'm having difficulties.

My route in the CP is set up as follows and works.

`/campaigns/{slug}/submissions`

My code to fetch the relating entry doesn't

`{% set entry = craft.entries.section('campaigns').slug('craft.app.request.getSegment(3)').one() %}
{{ entry.title }}`

This returns:

> Impossible to access an attribute ("title") on a null variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like there shouldn't be any quotes around `craft.app.request.getSegment(3)`

Also I'd use [named parameters](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/routing.html#accessing-named-parameters-in-your-templates) instead of .getSegment just seems a little bit more readable and robust.